# Add git remote only if it doesn't exist

Tags: git

Is there a easy way for a script to detect if a remote already exists and add it only if it doesn't? A plumbing command or porcelain flag?

When running `git remote add foo https://example.net` with an existing remote I get:

```
fatal: remote foo already exists.
```

Ideally there would be a flag such as `--if-not-exists` or `--update-if-exists` but I couldn't find any in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote).

I'm thinking of grepping the output of `git remote` but is there a better way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
git config remote.foo.url >&- || git remote add foo
```

git's written to handle closed fd's so you don't need `>/dev/null`, just close it, config sets a return code when you ask for a nonexistent config.

Comment: In general,  closing the file descriptor rather than redirecting to /dev/null is not a good idea, as there are undoubtedly tools whose exit status will be different.  (A quick sample shows that (on my box) cat, less, sed, and awk will all fail if stdout is closed, while grep and git-config do not notice the difference.) . There is no real reason to prefer closing instead of redirecting.

Comment: Agreed with @WilliamPursell . Here is more info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163959/228686 . It's a dangerous habit to acquire.

Comment: Good Lord. No, you can't often close the standard files instead of redirecting them to a bit bucket. But tools that handle it well include the few lines of code needed do so because `>&-`  is more convenient, they do so specifically as a convenience. And Git handles it well. As a general rule `>/dev/null` is absolutely the right one to teach children, but at some point repeating it goes beyond pedantry.

Comment: I guess there is a difference of opinion about "handling it well".  IMO, the proper way to handle a failed write to stdout is to immediately terminate rather than to just pretend there was no error.  I would argue that `git`'s failure to terminate with an error message is not at all "handling it well", but is a catastrophic failure.

Comment: @WilliamPursell the problem with that guess is, that's not how Git handles it.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer suggested in 2019:

> If the remote already exist:
>
> ```
> $ git remote add foo https://example.net
> fatal: remote foo already exists.
> $ echo $?                               
> 128
> ```

That does change with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021): exit codes from "[`git remote add/rename`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ecf95d938b390e1ee7c1df78b9ebe3a59ffd44c9/Documentation/git-remote.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote))</sup>
were not usable by scripted callers.

See [commit 9144ba4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9144ba4cf52bb0e891d7c10a331fc32c1d3e8f64) (27 Oct 2020) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ecf95d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecf95d938b390e1ee7c1df78b9ebe3a59ffd44c9), 09 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`remote`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9144ba4cf52bb0e891d7c10a331fc32c1d3e8f64): add meaningful exit code on missing/existing
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Change the exit code for the likes of "[`git remote add/rename`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9144ba4cf52bb0e891d7c10a331fc32c1d3e8f64/Documentation/git-remote.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote))</sup> to exit with 2 if the remote in question doesn't exist, and 3 if it does. Before we'd just `die()` and exit with the general 128 exit code.
>
> This changes the output message from e.g.:
>
> ```
> fatal: remote origin already exists.
> ```
>
> To:
>
> ```
> error: remote origin already exists.
> ```
>
> Which I believe is a feature, since we generally use "fatal" for the generic errors, and "error" for the more specific ones with a custom exit code, but this part of the change may break code that already relies on stderr parsing (not that we ever supported that...).
>
> The motivation for this is a discussion around some code in GitLab's gitaly which wanted to check this, and had to parse stderr to do so: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitaly/-/merge_requests/2695
>
> It's worth noting as an aside that a method of checking this that doesn't rely on that is to check with "[`git config`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9144ba4cf52bb0e891d7c10a331fc32c1d3e8f64/Documentation/git-config.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))</sup> whether the value in question does or doesn't exist. That introduces a [`TOCTOU` race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use), but on the other hand this code (e.g. "[`git remote add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9144ba4cf52bb0e891d7c10a331fc32c1d3e8f64/Documentation/git-remote.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote))</sup>) already has a `TOCTOU` race.
>
> We go through the config.lock for the actual setting of the config, but the pseudocode logic is:
>
> ```
> read_config();
> check_config_and_arg_sanity();
> save_config();
> ```
>
> So e.g. if a `sleep()` is added right after the `remote_is_configured()` check in `add()` we'll clobber `remote.NAME.url`, and add another (usually duplicate) `remote.NAME.fetch` entry (and other values, depending on invocation).

`git remote` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9144ba4cf52bb0e891d7c10a331fc32c1d3e8f64/Documentation/git-remote.txt#L206-L216):

> EXIT STATUS
>
> ---
>
> On success, the exit status is `0`.
>
> When subcommands such as '`add`', '`rename`', and '`remove`' can't find the
> remote in question, the exit status is `2`.
> When the remote already exists, the exit status is `3`.
>
> On any other error, the exit status may be any other non-zero value.

Answer (score 2):

Grep for the git remote name, and add it only if it does not exist. Then you can safely update the remote url:

```
git remote -v | grep -w foo || git remote add foo https://example.net 

git remote set-url foo https://example.net
```

Or if you prefer a oneliner:

```
git remote -v | grep -w foo && \
git remote set-url foo https://example.net || \
git remote add foo https://example.net
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm thinking of grepping the output of git remote but is there a
>   better way?

You can use the command exit code.

If the remote doesn't exist:

```
$ git remote add foo https://example.net
$ echo $?
0
```

If the remote already exist:

```
$ git remote add foo https://example.net
fatal: remote foo already exists.
$ echo $?                               
128
```

---

Edit:

This is fishy but I think it does what you want:

```
$ grep -q '\[remote "foo"\]' .git/config  || git remote add foo https://example.net
```

Comment: That would work but then I need `2> /dev/null || true` to avoid the error message and script failure (`set -e`). The end goal is only to make sure the remote exists not act upon whenever it exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git remote show <remote>`:

```
$ git remote show origin && echo ok || echo err
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: …
  Push  URL: …
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master rebases onto remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
ok

$ git remote show xxx && echo ok || echo err
fatal: 'xxx' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
err
```

Comment: As with the other answer the only drawback with this one is the need to suppress the messages with `> /dev/null 2>&1`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you want to add the remote or if it already exists, set the (first) remote URL:

```
git remote add origin URL || git remote set-url origin URL
```

This is safe in a script with `-e` even (and a script can also help to use variables here):

```
name=origin
url=URL
git remote add "$name" "$url" || git remote set-url "$name" "$url"
```

Working with local repositories only even allows to handle verify the URL as a local path (and make it absolute for the `git-config` operation).

---

I found out that just testing for the `remote.<name>.url` as suggested in other answers also had a false positive if it is unset (not that likely, but `git-remote add` then looks more complete to me for that test).

Also only relying on `git remote ...`  commands has less potential surprises than fiddling with the config.

Mind the gap: This suggestion is potentially incomplete at the point when you have to manage more than one URL per remote.